# SQL Developerでのdmpファイルインポート時のエラーが解決できません

Tags: sql, oracle

自分とは違うデータベースからエクスポートされたdmpファイルを自分のデータベースにインポートしたいのですが、SQL Developerでのdmpファイルインポート時に以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
例外:ORA-39001:引数値が無効です
dbms_datapump.get_status(数字...)
ORA-39001:引数値が無効です
ORA-39000:ダンプ・ファイル指定が無効です
ORA-39143:ダンプ・ファイル"C:\temp\M01.dmp"は、元のエクスポート・ダンプ・ファイルである場合があります
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

検索した結果、以下の様なケースがあることがわかりました。

> ORA-39000 ダンプ・ファイル指定が無効です
> 原因: 現行のジョブで使用できないダンプ・ファイルが指定されました。後続のエラー・メッセージに、不適切なダンプ・ファイルの箇所が記載されています。
> 処置: ジョブに使用できるダンプ・ファイルを指定してください。
>
> ORA-39001 引数値が無効です
> 原因: 誤まった型または値の範囲でAPIパラメータを指定しました。DBMS_DATAPUMP.GET_STATUSによって表示される後続のメッセージに、エラーが記載されています。
> 処置: 無効な引数を修正して、APIを再試行してください。
>
> ORA-39143 ダンプ・ファイル"string"は、元のエクスポート・ダンプ・ファイルである場合があります
> 原因: 元のエクスポート・ユーティリティを使用して作成した可能性のあるダンプ・ファイルがインポート操作に指定されました。これらのダンプ・ファイルは、Data Pumpインポート・ユーティリティで処理できません。
> 処置: このダンプ・ファイルは、元のインポート・ユーティリティを使用して処理してください。

おそらくdmpファイルがエラーの原因なのではないかと推測しますが、対策としての「このダンプ・ファイルは、元のインポート・ユーティリティを使用して処理してください。」という意味が分かりません。

いろいろ検索してみましたが対策が見つかりませんでしたので、質問させていただきました。
よろしくお願いいたします。

**実行環境:**

- windows10
- oracle12c(R2)
- oracle SQL Developer

Answer (score 1):

`exp.exe`で出力したデータを`impdp.exe`で読み込ませているために、ご質問のエラーが発生しているのではないのでしょうか。

SQL Developerのインポート/エクスポートは裏側で上記ツールのいずれかを呼び出しているはずですが、ツールは複数の種類に分かれています。
cf: [B SQL*Loader、エクスポートおよびインポートのInstant Client](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E96517_01/sutil/instant-client-sql-loader-export-import.html#GUID-27A52AD7-D11D-4460-80BD-6B1FAA3792DE)の表B-1 ツール・パッケージ内のInstant Clientファイル

古いデータベースから`exp.exe`(クラシックなエクスポートツール)で出力したデータは、`impdp.exe`(11g以降推奨されている新しいインポートツール)で読み込むことはできません。
下記いずれかの対応によりエラーを回避できることがあります。

- 移行元のデータベースで`expdp.exe`によるエクスポートを行う。
- 新しいデータベースに対して`imp.exe`を実行してインポートを行う。

  - SQL Developerのオプションを見直すか、コマンドラインから直接`imp.exe`を実行する必要がある
  - 11g以降は`exp.exe`/`imp.exe`が非推奨なので、18c以降に適用できるか不明(未確認)

cf: [Export/Importの使い方](https://blogs.oracle.com/oracle4engineer/exportimport)

Comment: @payaneco様　返信ありがとうございます。新しいデータベースでのimp.exeはうまくいかなかったので、移行元のデータベースでexpdp.exeによるエクスポートを行ってみようと思います。丁寧な対応ありがとうございました！